# Please let me edit my profile in Mobile theme

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, mobile-web, profile-edit

Just as the title says, I am unable to find the edit profile link in mobile view. It appears as though there isn't one. I think an edit profile link should be added somewhere beside the user's profile at least.

Comment: Do you mean to file a bug report or is this a feature request?

Comment: I don't know if it was by design or not, so I don't know if I should call it a bug. I can only guess that you should be able to edit your profile in mobile view by default, therefore a bug since it's not there?

Comment: @Xarcell Pretty sure this is by design.

Comment: I've changed this to a feature request as there's no mobile editing interface for the profile.

Answer (score 8):

When the profile "about me" section is blank there is a link on the mobile view profile page stating:

> (Your about me is currently blank. )
>    Click here to edit

The last line is a link to the (non mobile friendly) edit profile area.

So everyone without text in their profile area does have a link to edit their profile in mobile view.

Suggest removing that link, or, preferably, making the edit profile area mobile friendly. Once you have the profile area mobile friendly, could it also be rolled out to the app as well? Would be a nice feature to add to the app :)