# Edit profile on mobile?

Tags: support, mobile-app, profile-edit

I currently do not have access to a computer and I want to edit my Stack Exchange profile.

Is this even possible on the mobile app? I can't find any button to edit or anything similar.

Comment: Feature request for mobile-web: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180851/please-let-me-edit-my-profile-in-mobile-theme/267324

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't edit your profile using the mobile app. However, if you're using Chrome on Android or Safari on iOS, you can load the desktop version of the site and make your edits there:

1. Visit your profile on the Stack Exchange site that you want to edit your profile on.
2. For mobile Chrome, go to the menu and choose "Request desktop site". For mobile Safari, tap the address bar, swipe down, and choose "Request Desktop Site".
3. The Stack Exchange desktop site will load, and you can pan-and-zoom your way around to the profile edit page and make your edits.