# Username showing up like an anonymous user

Tags: support, android-app, user-accounts

I signed up a few days back all proper, verified and all, but my username still shows up as "user21414". Is this because I need a certain reputation?

Comment: You need to [edit your profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) and write the name you want in the "Display Name" field. It's not being imported from your OpenID provider automatically

Comment: @ShadowWizard The option to edit profile does not show up, and the link you've provided displays a 'page not found' page.

Comment: Weird. Can you please go to [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/306675/user21414) and post screenshot of what you see? You can upload the screenshot to http://imgur.com

Comment: @ShadowWizard Er, I don't have the imgur app. Just tell me where on that page (how did you get the link in the comment?!) I can find the edit profile option.

Comment: Don't think you need the app to upload images, anyway [here is screenshot of my profile](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0NcTV.png), do you also see the "Edit Profile & Settings" link? If not, you might be in the mobile view, that does not support editing the profile. Click the "full site" link in the footer, and you should see what I see.

Comment: Related: feature-request for edit profile on mobile-web: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180851/please-let-me-edit-my-profile-in-mobile-theme/267324 - though still remains to be confirmed if lack of access is the issue here, or if user has changed username and has not worked.

Comment: @James Access is the issue. I'm using the app, and the option to edit does not show up anywhere on my profile page.

Comment: @user21414 In which case upvote the feature request ;)

Comment: @user21414 what app? iOS or android? You didn't use proper tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you first create an account, the default display name is the word "user" followed by the unique ID on the site where the account is created.

In order to change this, you must edit your profile. However, the android app does not support editing the profile. There is already a [pending feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201594/ability-to-update-profile-from-the-stackexchange-android-app) asking to add the ability to edit profile via the app, but since the app is currently unsupported, it's extremely unlikely we'll see that feature implemented.

Bottom line: if you want a different display name, you must use a web browser, and if on mobile, make sure to go to "full site" mode, there is a link in the footer, since the mobile view of the website also does not support editing the profile and has no link to the edit page. (and yet again, there is a [pending feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180851/please-let-me-edit-my-profile-in-mobile-theme) asking to add such ability.)